# Query onto a dynamoDb table

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I am trying to get all the records of a database that meet a filter that I already defined. The problem with this is that I am having to repeat it N times depending on the number of organizations. Is there a way to make it iterate for each of the organizations?
I tried putting the organization_code in an array but it fails saying that the schema is not correct. Please help

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
AWS.config.update({ region: 'us-east-2' })
const dDBClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
const async = require('async')
let scanComplete = false


let beginDate = "2020-12-16 00:00:00.000"
let endDate = "2020-12-23 00:00:00.000"
const organization_code = "CLPIT01DB" < - HERE ARE JUST 1 ORG, NEED 6 of them!

const params = {
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':organization_code': organization_code,
        ':BeginDate': beginDate,
        ':EndDate': endDate
    },
    KeyConditionExpression: 'organization_code = :organization_code',
    ProjectionExpression: `booking_id,booking_payment_ids,booking_pnr,company_address,company_city,company_comuna,company_girototal_amount_clp,total_amount_exe,total_amount_vat,vat`,
    FilterExpression: 'payment_createdutc >= :BeginDate and payment_createdutc < :EndDate',
    TableName: 'TemporaryPayments'
}
```

[restOfTheCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nd0sn.png)
[TableConfiguration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38nyv.png)

Thank you very much!

Comment: I guess you don't have sort key on the scheme? So it won't work as expectation for that case. From your case, I assume you try to query some rows on the specific date range.

Comment: nope, finally i did a forEach with the organizations but still need to put a setTimeOut because the await doesnt work for me... any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
AWS.config.update({ region: 'us-east-2' })
const dDBClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

let beginDate = "2020-12-16 00:00:00.000"
let endDate = "2020-12-23 00:00:00.000"
let arrayData = []; // init list of query data

// Initiate the params
let params = {
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ':BeginDate': beginDate,
      ':EndDate': endDate
    },
    KeyConditionExpression: 'organization_code = :organization_code',
    ProjectionExpression: `booking_id,booking_payment_ids,booking_pnr,company_address,company_city,company_comuna,company_girototal_amount_clp,total_amount_exe,total_amount_vat,vat`,
    FilterExpression: 'payment_createdutc >= :BeginDate and payment_createdutc < :EndDate',
    TableName: 'TemporaryPayments'
}

async function db_query(org_code) {
  params.ExpressionAttributeValues = {
    ...params.ExpressionAttributeValues,
    {
      ':organization_code': org_code
    }
  }
  let res = await dDBClient.query(params).promise();
  arrayData = [
    ...arrayData,
    res.Items
  ]
  if (res.LastEvaluatedKey) {
    params.ExclusiveStartKey = res.LastEvaluatedKey;
    return db_query(org_code);
  }
  console.log(org_code+" data length : "+arrayData.length)
  arrayData = [];
}

db_query("CLPIT01DB")
```

You can iterate the organization queries by doing this :

```
const org_codes = ["CLPIT01DB", "xxxxxxxxx", etc];
let org_queries = [];
org_codes.forEach(org => {
  org_queries.push(db_query(org));
})
Promise.all(org_queries)
```